# Jboss 7 war deployment failed

Tags: deployment, jboss, war

Jboss 7 war deployment failed and i got the below error message in the log.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment
```

I tried restarting the JBoss server, I have never seen this before, it was working fine before. I googled around for solution and cause of this issue but cant find anything really useful, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well I tried deleting the log file, it helped at the beginning but then I got the error again. The proper solution is as following:

Go to `Jboss_installation_dir\standalone\configuration` and find the file `standalone.xml`. Change the following line:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
    <deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments"  />
</subsystem>
```

into:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.0">
    <deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments" deployment-timeout="1000" />
</subsystem>
```

then it should work fine.

**NOTE:** This `deployment-timeout` is in seconds

Comment: is this timeout value in Sec? or milli-sec?

Comment: in seconds. the default is 60 seconds, just make it something large enough, now it is 1000 seconds for example

Answer (score 8):

It was caused by insufficient space on the disk, cleared some unwanted log files and other temp files to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with JBoss 7 (6.1+ EAP) remember to edit XML settings only when the server is not running - otherwise they will be overwritten and the changes will not take place.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Deployment+Scanner+configuration), `Deployment-timeout` is specified in seconds and `Scan-interval` time is specified in miliseconds.