# Unable to start JBoss-as-7.1.1 in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to debug a servlet. After setting the break point and launching jboss in debug mode, the application hangs and eventually times out and throws a set of errors.

```
00:00:57,692 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
00:00:58,404 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
00:00:58,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
00:01:01,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
00:01:01,252 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
00:01:01,290 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
00:01:01,321 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
00:01:01,392 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
00:01:01,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
00:01:01,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
00:01:01,491 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
00:01:01,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
00:01:01,588 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
00:01:01,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
00:01:01,676 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
00:01:01,851 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
00:01:01,887 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
00:01:01,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
00:01:02,195 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
00:01:02,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
00:01:02,430 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
00:01:02,527 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
00:01:03,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Utils\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
00:01:03,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
00:01:03,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
00:01:03,621 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found StudentManagementEJB.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called StudentManagementEJB.jar.dodeploy
00:01:03,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found BooksPoint.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called BooksPoint.war.dodeploy
00:01:03,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found DynamicWebProject1.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called DynamicWebProject1.war.dodeploy
00:01:03,628 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found StudentManagement.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called StudentManagement.war.dodeploy
00:01:03,629 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found BooksPointEJB.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called BooksPointEJB.jar.dodeploy
00:01:03,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found HelloWorldSessionBean.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HelloWorldSessionBean.jar.dodeploy
```

The errors given are:

```
00:02:04,464 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "BooksPoint.war")]) - failure description: "Operation cancelled asynchronously"
00:02:04,466 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
00:02:04,475 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
00:02:04,481 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
00:02:04,486 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
00:02:04,492 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.
```

I have a batch file that creates the required .dodeploy files:

**deploy.bat**

```
echo " " > HelloWorldSessionBean.jar.dodeploy && echo " " > StudentManagementEJB.jar.dodeploy &&  echo " " > DynamicWebProject1.war.dodeploy && echo " " > BooksPoint.war.dodeploy && echo " " > StudentManagement.war.dodeploy
```

The files are already created before launching the server. I have also tried increasing the deployment timeout as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001342/jboss-7-war-deployment-failed). The server, however, still hangs and eventually times out even with the extended timeout.
Is there any workaround to this issue?

Comment: Shutdown the server, remove any application deployed, and start it again, then deploy your app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an excessive number of breakpoints in Eclipse?  Try removing some/all breakpoints.